# Strange behaviour in IE 11 and symfony 2.3.2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

This is strange. I have published a site with a login page at start. when i use Firefox or Chrome, I can login to the site correctly. when /login_check action is ran, it validates correctly and do the corresponding redirect.

However, this does not work in IE 11. Then I enter a correct login information, after login_check, browser redirects to the same login page.

When I enter invalid credentials, login_check redirects again to login page but with no message. This happens in both debug or production environments. In dev.log file no error is saved.

Any hint about this problem?

This is Symfony 2.3.2